# Old VS10 project compile error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, porting

I recently took over an old project which was build with .NET4 and VS10. I've tried opening this in VS15 Enterprise, though I've encountered some problems when compiling.

I get 606 errors with:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1056  Unexpected character '
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs.

All errors is withing AssemlyAttributes.cs - how do I fix this? I've tried googling, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Have you checked the project file for possible errors? If not, search the project file for the line: '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.

Comment: Please don't abbreviate the year numbers to two digits. The *only* version in recent years where the VS version number and its marketing year matched was 2010. Visual Studio 2015 is version 14.

Comment: No errors in the file. :)
Thx for the slap, Damien, I'll make sure to remember that!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with adding:

```
<Target Name="GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" /> below 
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

In all project files :) THanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same error.When i checked the path C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs the file was blank.
So added the folowing in the file.

using System;

using System.Reflection;

[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.0")]

This solved my problem.